# Simplest way to pass property to a UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have two UITableViewControllers (hooked up to a UINavigationController).  When I click on a UITableViewCell on the first controller, I created a segue so that the second controller comes into view.  I want to have a variable in the second view controller that contains the text on the that was selected.  How do I do this?  I have tried passing it directly, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an property (like selectedText - an NSString) on the receiving viewcontroller (in this case we'll call it SecondTableViewController).  Here is the code:

In SecondTableViewController.h:

```
@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedText;
```

In SecondTableViewController.m:

```
@implementation SecondTableViewController
@synthesize messageDetail;
```

In your FirstTableViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure we are dealing with the proper Segue
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"idOfMySegue"]) {
        SecondTableViewController *svc = segue.destinationViewController;
        svc.selectedText = myVarValue; // This can be got from either setting another var in the tableviewcontroller or by just passing the entire object at the selected index of the NSIndexPath.row (if you are populating the tableview with an array.  Note you would change the object type of the passed along object from an NSString to whatever the other object is.
    }
}
```

The prepareForSeque method is where you pass along any data or objects from one view to another.

Comment: the only problem is I can't access any class properties inside prepareForSegue (the class that prepareForSegue is typed in)

Comment: You can access those as long as you include a reference to the SecondTableViewController in your FirstTableViewController.m file

Comment: If you send me what you have now I will try to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: Please give me an example of how to set `svc.selectedText` to a property declared in my first view controller (inside of prepareForSegue)

Comment: svc.selectedText is a property in your secondVC. The prepareForSegue method knows the properties declared in your destination viewcontoller (SecondTableViewController). If you will send me the code of both view controllers, I will tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I really hesitate to give the code away because of personal reasons.  If you can't answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766796/how-do-i-use-a-property-in-prepareforsegue then I will be happy to give you the code