# How do I use a property in -prepareForSegue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is my code, posted in view1:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toLevels"])
    {
        levelViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        vc.currentEnchantmentSelected = self.title;
    }
}
```

This doesn't send the value of "self.title" to the variable in "levelViewController".  Why is this?  It sends it if I use a string.

Edit (`levelViewController`):

```
@synthesize enchantment = _enchantment;
- (enchantmentViewController *)enchantment
{
    if (!_enchantment){
        _enchantment = [[enchantmentViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return _enchantment;
}
```

the `@property enchantment` is declared in the header.

Comment: What do you mean by "it sends it if I use a string". Can you show in code what you were doing that worked? Is `currentEnchantmentSelected` a view?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer If I change `self.title` to `@"random text"`, I coded levelViewController so that its title changes to `vc.currentEnchantmentSelected`.  `currentEnchantmentSelected` is a property in `levelViewController`.  So the title changes if I use a string, but doesn't change if I use a property.  I have tried this with many other properties and I still don't get anything on the title on `levelViewController`

Comment: ok, then did you check that self.title isn't nil? And can you show the declaration of `currentEnchantmentSelected`?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer I think all properties are nil for some reason (all the properties which I use `self` to access).  code edited

Comment: Oh, and the obvious question, do you have any compiler warnings?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer my bad, enchantement should read enchantmentViewController.  its defined in enchantmentViewController (which I previously said was view1)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6498/discussion-between-firoze-lafeer-and-blake305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the chat, the issue was that you were setting this property in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, which is actually called *after* `prepareForSegue:sender:` with storyboards. (when the segue is attached to a cell in a table)

So the solution is just to do that work directly in `prepareForSegue:sender:` instead. The `sender` will be the cell that was tapped. And if you need the indexPath for that cell you can use:

```
[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

Good luck with the app.